# How to stop paper curling up

Tags: substitute-tool, stationery, office-supplies

Sometimes paper is stored in a roll, mainly drawings or wrapping paper. When you try and lay it out flat it attempts to go back into a roll meaning you have to hold down the edges all the time.

> **How can I keep the paper from attempting to roll back up?**

As an extra, a way of **keeping** it flat, so if I don't want to store it again in a roll, it won't go back into that shape!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always try to roll it the other way around, which will remove some of the curl in the paper when unrolled again.

Another option if you don't mind creases in the paper is to make a crease in the direction of the curl. Creases don't curl easily.

Answer (score 4):

With the curled face down on the table iron it with the iron set to the minimum temperature. If the paper is too thin, then iron with a piece of cloth over the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Lay it on the table with the curling side face down. Then use a paperweight or similar object heavy enough to hold down each corner.

Comment: What if I need the information on the side it is curling on?